# Unable to make ASP.NET control button fade out with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a simple enough problem: I have an ASP.NET control button and I want to make it fade out and then call some function (such as an alert) using JQuery. Here is what I have so far:

ASP Code for the Button:

```
<div id="begin">
        <span id="startButtonSpan">
            <asp:Button ID="startButton" class="startButton" runat="server" Text="Click Me!" OnClientClick="startButtonClick()"/>
        </span>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function startButtonClick()
{
    $("#startButtonSpan > input").fadeOut(500, callAlert());
}

function callAlert()
{
    alert("Made it here...");
}
```

When I click the button, the alert displays but the page does not even seem to try to perform the fadeOut. When I close the alert, the button is still there, staring at me.

Can anyone see any mistakes or does anyone have any suggestions on how I might be able to achieve the intended goal of fading out my button? Fadeout is really just my way of testing whether I can manipulate ASP controls using jQuery, so more than just the simple fadeOut, this is me trying to learn how to do that.

I tried a slightly more simple jQuery call using the code below, but it does not seem to work either:

ASP Portion:

```
<div id="begin">
        <span id="startButtonSpan">
            <asp:Button ID="startButton" class="startButton" runat="server" Text="Click Me!" OnClientClick="startButtonClick()"/>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div id="jQueryTest" style="display:none;">
        Block for testing jQuery.
        <h1 id="testMessage">Child element for the ASP div.</h1>
    </div>
```

Javascript Portion:

```
function startButtonClick()
{
    $("#jQueryTest").css("display", "block");
    $("#jQueryTest").show();
}
```

For this example, the text does display, but it immediately disappears again.

Any help or suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using MasterPages?

Comment: Yes, I am using a Master page.

Comment: I provided an answer for you that pertains to MasterPages. It may work for you. It has helped me in more robust applications. I dummed it down for this example, but the gist of it is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the fact that your code is fine (although other answers here should be considered) but your button is making a post back to the server and simply your browser does not have enough time to render the fade effect.

To test this, add a `return false;` to the `OnClientClick` property. This will of course cancel your action on the server but you will obtain the fade effect:

```
 <asp: Button ... OnClientClick="startButtonClick();return false;"></asp:Button>
```

To work around this and still submit your request, you can try to use the ASP.NET `__doPostBack` method in JavaScript

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:Button ID="startButton" class="startButton" runat="server" Text="Click Me!" OnClientClick="startButtonClick(this);return false;"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
function startButtonClick(button)
{
    $("#startButtonSpan > input").fadeOut(500, function(){__doPostBack(button.name, "")});
}
```

The `__doPostBack` method takes two arguments: the name of the control that is doing the postback and a postback argument that can be use to send more info on the server. In the case of the `asp:Button`, the name of the button should be sufficient to send the request without a problem.

Using this technique you will fade the button on the client and also trigger the action on the server. I cannot guarantee that this exact code will work (I don't have access to a dev environment right now) but you should get the idea.

Comment: Thank you so much! The postback appears to have been the problem and the code is now functioning as intended. =)

Answer (score 3):

Use the class as a selector `$('.startButton')` instead of the ID since ASP.Net controls change their IDs dynamically when rendered by appending its Page & Control information.

```
$(".startButton").fadeOut(500, callAlert);
```

Or, if you're adamant about using the ID, here is another way to handling the selector,

```
$("#<%=startButton.ClientID %>")
```

Or, as Jacob suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19551147/370671), you could `ClientIDMode="Static"`, but this works only if your application is .Net 4.0 or above.

Also, use `CssClass` instead of `class`

```
<asp:Button ID="startButton" Csslass="startButton" runat="server" Text="Click Me!" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! Unfortunately it is still not working. After changing the reference to both of the suggestions (as well as just ".startButton" and also to ".startButtonSpan > input"), no fadeOut occurs. The only difference is that changing from callAlert() to just callAlert causes the alert message to not show up anymore.

Comment: @user2912928 instead of class use `CssClass="startButton"`. Also, use `#startButtonSpan` since its not a class.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers! =) The problem turned out to be the postback issue, but the different selector options are very helpful (as well as calling me out on the CssClass).

Answer (score 1):

The first example has 2 problems.

**1.** You should write

```
$("#startButton").fadeOut(500, callAlert);
```

and not

```
$("#startButton").fadeOut(500, callAlert());
```

**2.** For ASP.NET you must set ClientIDMode="Static" ortherwise asp.net will alter your id.

```
<asp:Button ID="startButton" ClientIDMode="Static" ... OnClientClick="startButtonClick()"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Changing the callAlert function now stops the alert from showing up. Unfortunately, changing the ClientIDMode to static did not seem to help, as the button still does not fade out or give any indication of trying to do so. With ClientIDMode set to Static, I tried this with both "#startButtonSpan > input" and with "#startButton" as the jQuery search parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If I could, I would like to provide another answer for those that use **MasterPages** and find that you can't always use `$("#<%= SomeContentControl.ClientID %>")` when working with Content controls.

What I do is set the MasterPage ID in my `Init()` like this:

```
protected void Page_Init( object sender, EventArgs e ) 
{
    // this must be done in Page_Init or the controls 
    // will still use "ctl00_xxx", instead of "Mstr_xxx"

    this.ID = "Mstr"; 
}
```

Then, you can do something like this with your jQuery:

```
var masterId = "Mstr",
    $startButton = getContentControl("startButton"),
    $message = $("#jQueryTest");

function getContentControl( ctrlId )
{
    return $("#" + masterId + "_" + ctrlId);
}

function hideStartButton()
{
    $startButton
        .stop(true, true)
        .fadeOut("slow", showMessage);
}

function showMessage()
{
    $message
        .stop(true, true)
        .fadeIn("slow");
}

$startButton.on("click",  hideStartButton);
```

Here is a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U6j95/) that has the `Mstr_` prefix already inserted as if ASP.NET rendered it.